# simple css issue - dont know where to fix

Tags: html, css

i am trying to fix this css thing, but i cannot do it somehow, i am not also css guru actually. so i turned to ask this here.

the problem is in [this](http://doni.sites.djangoeurope.com/) page, in the last slider header on the right: "Locations eintragen".

the bottom half of this last div is in chrome a bit hidden,
[image]

if you see it in Firefox, this is shown correctly. how can I fix this? i want that it should be like in Firefox.

appreciate any help.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here (HTML snippet, related CSS). Links to live sites (or even jsfiddle) are not sufficient, nor are images.

Comment: From a quick view in Firefox, it is also incorrect, or maybe it's just me.

Comment: @s0d4pop, really? in my ff, it is correct, can you pls check it again?

Comment: @doniyor: Yes, it is still cut off in FF. I don't know why we differ, maybe my version of FF is outdated while yours is up to date, or vice versa.

Comment: Going off of Jonathan's answer, you have to find the element's CSS properties. From what I see, these properties can be found in **Slidorion.css, Line 244.**. Change the **height** property to a smaller value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the accordion that contains your menu items has its height set to 400px, limiting the height of the items contained in it. You should set the height to another value, or remove limitation.

Hint: you should press F12 in Chrome to bring up the developers' tools. From there, you can right click on elements on your page and choose "inspect element". Then you will be able to see what styles are being inherited, disable and alter them to see effect, etc.

Comment: thanks, i will see it